# multiple functioning using java and spring framework

Tags: java, spring, task

I am using spring ,

I need to send mail to nearly 10000 users.Now i am waiting in that page till all mails are 
   sent.but i dont want to wait.I need to give that task to some class which will execute 
   automatically after handover,then i need to continue with my task.

How i can do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would use Quartz for scheduling tasks like mail sending, etc: http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: mail sending is an example only.I have some other tasks

Answer (score 5):

The @Async Annotation

```
The @Async annotation can be provided on a method so that invocation
```

of that method will occur asynchronously. In other words, the caller 
will return immediately upon invocation and the actual execution of 
the method will occur in a task that has been submitted to a Spring TaskExecutor.

[source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: we are using spring 2.5.6 version

Comment: u can use "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" for spring 2.5.6 version http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

> I need to give that task to some class which will execute automatically after handove

This is a clear clue to Use `Threads`. Create a Thread on server side and  handover to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Quartz (http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to start a job that will send all the emails.

Comment: Quartz really sucks in a clustered environment.